# Looking for papers that talk like this about types

Tags: haskell, types

I'm writing a bachelor's thesis on a Haskell topic that deals with fix points, and so I tried making all that type stuff rigorous. I made up types as follows:

[image]

Do you know papers that use this definition or a close one?

Answer (score 2):

That's Scott semantics, named after Dana Scott, who really invented this. I guess you can find it in his works.

Oh, and such oredered sets are called "domains", so, domain semantics is another name for the same things. There are various refinements of this that allow things like higher-rank types.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is not typically called a "type". Rather, it is usually called a [*domain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory), which is used in [denotational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics). For fixed points, such domains are often taken to be [complete partial orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_partial_order) (CPOs). These might come in different "flavours", like omega-CPOs or DCPOS.

If you can, have a look at [domain theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory) which is described in some programming languages textbooks, such as the Winskel formal semantics book.